# how to change typeface of dialogMessage of EditTextPreference in Android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

How can I change typeface of dialogMessage of EditTextPreference in Android?

I want to change the default font style of the dialog, but I don't know how do it!

this is my Custom EditTextPreference:

```
public class MyEditTextPreferences extends EditTextPreference {

public MyEditTextPreferences(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


public MyEditTextPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}


public MyEditTextPreferences(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}


@Override
protected void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    TextView summaryView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
    titleView.setTypeface(G.yekanfont);
    summaryView.setTypeface(G.yekanfont);

} 
}
```

and this:

```
 <com.mydomain.mypackagename.MyEditTextPreferences
    android:defaultValue="300"
    android:dialogMessage="some text"
    android:dialogTitle="some other text"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:key="DURATION_BETWEEN"
    android:title="some text"        
    android:summary="some other text"
     />
```

Comment: put dialogMessage custom layout and the code where you inflate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in onCreateView. Like this:

```
@Override
protected View onCreateView(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(viewGroup);
    try {
        TextView titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        titleView.setTypeface(G.yekanfont);
        TextView summaryView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.summary);
        summaryView.setTypeface(G.yekanfont);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Excpetion ", e);
    }

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a custom EditTextPreference class. Just do the following:

```
EditTextPreference preferenceEditText = (EditTextPreference) findPreference(itsKey);
EditText editText = preferenceEditText.getEditText();
//Now do whatever you want with this EditText
```

And to change the font face of the title and summary, in your `styles.xml`, do the following:

```
<style name="PreferenceTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
    ...
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/lato</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/lato</item>
</style>
```

Not sure which one works, so I just put both `android:fontFamily` and `fontFamily`. To apply the style, go to your Preference Fragment class:

```
private ViewGroup parent;
...

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    parent = container;
    ...
}
...
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    parent.getContext().setTheme(R.style.PreferenceTheme);
}
```